# How to use two conditions in Linq lambda which has different where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to query my item in table Items, where the last update of each item must be less than 91 days old (from last update till now) and the quantity > 0.
This is my code in the Model:

```
public IList<Item> GetAllProducts()
{
 var ien_item = from i in this.DataContext.Items  
 orderby i.LastUpdated descending
 select i;
 return ien_item.ToList().Where(
                 s =>
                 HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(s.LastUpdated.Value) == true 
                 && 
                 (s => s.Quantity) > 0
                 )
                 .ToList();

}
```

Anyone can solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Solve what, exactly? You've presented some code - does it work? Note that the `ToList()` means that your query will be performed entirely at the client side, which seems like a bad idea to me... but assuming you're happy with that, what's not working?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It seem appeared error with my query but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Your query look ok except that instead of "&& (s => s.Quantity) > 0", you could use just "&& s.Quantity > 0"

Comment: @socheata: What do you mean by "it seem appeared error"? If you got an error, you should tell us what error that was. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - the more information you provide about what's going wrong, the more likely we are to be able to help.

Comment: Please add your error message to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't really know what's not working here. EDIT: Merlyn spotted it; your lambda syntax is messed up. There's more to do here though.

However, I'd have *thought* you'd want this:

```
public IList<Item> GetAllProducts()
{
     var lastUpdateLimit = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-91);
     var query = from item in DataContext.Items
                 where item.Quantity > 0 && item.LastUpdated >= lastUpdateLimit
                 orderby item.LastUpdated descending
                 select item;
     return query.ToList();
}
```

Note that this is able to do all the querying at the database side instead of fetching *all* the items and filtering at the client side. It does assume that `HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate` is simple though, and basically equivalent to the filter I've got above.

(One additional point to note is that by evaluating `UtcNow.Date` *once*, the result will be consistent for all items - whereas if your code evaluates "today" on every call to `IsLastUpdate`, some values in the query may end up being filtered against a different date to other values, due to time progressing while the query is evaluating.)

EDIT: If you *really* need to use `HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate` then I'd suggest:

```
public IList<Item> GetAllProducts()
{
     var query = from item in DataContext.Items
                 where item.Quantity > 0
                 orderby item.LastUpdated descending
                 select item;
     return query.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(s => HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(s.LastUpdated.Value))
                 .ToList();
}
```

... then at least the quantity filter is performed at the database side, and you're not creating a complete buffered list before you need to (note the single call to `ToList`).

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, It could not query like this because the LastUpdated must be qualify by the method isLastUpdate() in my Helper class, so I cannot use this method in query.

Comment: @socheata: Well what does that method *do*? It would be much more efficient if you could express that logic in the query so that it could be performed at the server side. Basically I'm afraid you haven't given us enough information here - I wrote a query matching your description of "where the last updated of each item must less than 91 days". Is there more logic in `IsLastUpdated`?

Comment: This query work perfectly if I write only: `code`return ien_item.ToList().Where(
                                    s => HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(s.LastUpdated.Value) == true
                                     
                                 )
                           .ToList(); But when I added the clause about the quantity , It error.

Comment: @socheata: "it error" isn't very descriptive. What was the error? Please read the article I linked to.

Comment: If I put that query, all my item that have quality = 0 not show in my page, But actually although quality = 0 , it still show on page if the lastUpdate <=91 .

Comment: @socheata: It really shouldn't - are you sure you haven't changed my query somewhere? And are you also sure you're not confusing quality and quantity? You've used both terms in various places. Both queries I've given *will* filter out items with a quantity of 0. It's actually not clear what you're seeing, as your last comment seems to contradict itself - first you say that the items don't show, then that they do...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your lambda syntax.  You're trying to define a second lambda while in the middle of defining a first lambda.  While this is possible to do, and useful in some contexts, it is sort of an advanced scenario, and probably won't be useful to you until you know you need it.

Right now, you don't need it.  Unless you know you need it, you don't need it :)

**So -**

Instead of what you've written:

```
.Where(
    s =>
        HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(s.LastUpdated.Value) == true 
            && (s => s.Quantity) > 0
    )
```

Write this instead:

```
.Where(
    s =>
        HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(s.LastUpdated.Value) == true 
            && s.Quantity > 0 // Notice I got rid of the extra lambda here
    )
```

*If you're morbidly curious:*

The compile error you got is because you didn't define your second lambda correctly.  It redefined a variable you'd already used (`s`), and you were trying to check if a *lambda* was greater than zero.  That makes no sense.  You can only compare the *result* of a lambda to some value.  It's like calling a function.  You don't compare functions to numbers - you compare the *result* you get when *calling* a function to a number.

Comment: No promises this will fix everything, but this is an error that is obvious to me, and having this error would break your code.  If there are more problems, keep the info coming :)  And give full error messages (add them to the question)

Comment: Description of my lambda : The item will not show in my page anymore if : the last update of each item =91 days old (from last update till now), and the quality = 0. But if the quality = 0 and the last update of each item <= 91 days old (from last update till now), the item still show in page.

Comment: @socheata: That's not part of this question, so you should really post another question (or simply learn boolean logic).  But I'll try to help anyhow.  Your where clause should match your "item will still show in page" logic.  So you want `Where(s => DateTime.Today - s.LastUpdated.Date <= TimeSpan.FromDays(91) && s.Quantity == 0)`

Comment: @socheata: If you've gotten past the compiler error, and that previous comment didn't help, then please post another question.  It is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easy ...

```
public IList<Item> GetAllProducts()
{
     var ien_item = 
          from i in DataContext.Items
          where 
               HelperClasses.HelperClass.IsLastUpdate(i.LastUpdated.Value)
               && s.Quantity > 0
          orderby i.LastUpdated descending
          select i;

     return ien_item.ToList();
}
```

Linq to SQL: Methods are not allowed (linq is not magic and can not convert C# methods to TSQL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Linq to Object: while looking the same, it is much more powerful than linq to SQL... but can not query SQL databases :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx

Linq to XML: same as linq to Object, with xml object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Linq to Dataset: not the same as Linq to SQL !
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx

Other linq providers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query

Comment: The is the method of IsLastUpdated():    public static bool IsLastUpdate(DateTime dt)
        {

            bool _isLastUpdate = false;

            DateTime _today = DateTime.Now;

            TimeSpan _timespan = _today.Subtract(dt);

            _isLastUpdate = (Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0:00}", _timespan.TotalDays)) <= 91);

            return _isLastUpdate;

        } `code`

Comment: This is the detail that I want : 1. If(lastUpdated >=91 && quality=<){ //the item show}. 2. If(lastUpdated >=91 && quality <=0){ //item show}. 3. If(lastUpdated >91 && quality = 0){//item not show}. 4. if(lastUpdated>91 && Quality >0){//item show}.

Comment: No it is not an error to use a method in "Linq to objects". Although it is an error to use a method in "Linq to SQL". It is also not an error to use a method in "Linq to XML". In your sample you are using "Linq to objects" not "Linq to SQL".